# How To Call External API Using Google App Script via URLFetch Class

Tags: google-apps-script

```
function checkACBalance() {
  try{
    var url ="http://sms.mydomain.com/api/balance.php";
    alert(url);
    var payload = {authkey:'d5558466554f11aa909d565ede677d40', route:'1'};
    alert(payload);
    var payload_json = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(payload));
    alert(payload_json);
    var options =  {method:"POST",contentType:"application/json",payload:payload_json,muteHttpExceptions:true};
    var result = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
    var response = result.getContentText();
    alert(response)
    var res_code = result.getResponseCode();
    alert(res_code)
  }catch(e){
    alert(e)
  }
}
```

Now the problem is that when I am using this `URLFetch` Class for calling external API then this is not working.
In browser console an error has been shown:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fetch' of undefined

Comment: Where exatcly is this `checkACBalance` funciton? Betweeen HTML <script> code in a GAS `code.gs` file?

Comment: I have three files for this. Sidebar.html (for HTML), SidebarJS.html (For Javascript) and Stylesheet.html (For CSS Stylesheet). checkACBalance function in SidebarJS.html

Answer (score 0):

To build on what Kriggs is saying in the comments, it looks like you're trying to use `UrlFetchApp.fetch` in your `.js` file (the client). You want to make this call in your `.gs` file (the server).

Comment: Can you explain this with a suitable example?